# why equals method must have equality operator comparison

Tags: java

```
When we override equals method we write the code as below
 public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    //why do we need to use this piece of code
        **if (obj == this) {
            return true;
        }**
```

// How does the above two lines help. Instead I do not want to have the == on an object comparison
//I prefer to remove the above 2 lines. Will it cause any issue?

```
        if (obj == null || obj.getClass() != this.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }

        Person guest = (Person) obj;
        return id == guest.id
                && (firstName == guest.firstName
                     || (firstName != null && firstName.equals(guest.getFirstName())))
                && (lastName == guest.lastName
                     || (lastName != null && lastName .equals(guest.getLastName())));
    }
```

Comment: Why do you need to check first name and last name when ID alone more than enough ?

Comment: @vels4j may be before saving them , in a persistence context ??

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ Hmm.. then its wrong design.

Comment: @vels4j May be. I'm not sure. Just an assumption of mine. You may also correct. Let Op decide on it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What will you do if the two object references are pointing to the same object. There is no need to actually check the `firstName` and `lastName` inside them for equality once both are pointing to the same instance. The above code is to make your logic perform better when the two references are pointing to the same object. It's a clean, perfect and good practice code style which leverage the performance. Please don't remove it.

Comment: Thanks this makes sense and I agree with you. Reason why it is good for performance is that it executes the first condition and returns true.As you mentioned it need not go and check the other attributes explicitly

Answer (score 2):

Performance improvement  and as well as some logical sense.

If you remove that, there is no harm.

But, there is no meaning of checking the  conditions on same instance if both are pointing to same instance.

They are always `true` if `obj == this`. Think.

Answer (score 0):

Since comparison of references is very effective and object definitely equals to itself comparison of references (`if(obj == this)`) seems to be a good practice.

Comment: But when does the code enter into this condition?? When I just say Person p1 = new Person(); Person p2= new Person(); It executes the other part of code and returns true. I cannot think of a case where it enters into this condition. Also when I use tools for static testing, they complain me of the condition, cannot use Reference Equality Comparison on objects

Answer (score 0):

== sign is used to measure the object reference.If the Object is being compared with itself,it should always be true.

There should be no wastage in terms of overhead in comparing of Object's own attributes as they would always be equal.

**Attributes should be measured when the two Objects refer to different Objects in HEAP**